# Would changing the expiry header for `analytics.js` from Google Analytics mess things up?

Tags: apache, analytics, cache, expiry

I'm using GTMetrix to help figure ways to speed up my page load times. One of the suggestions is to Leverage Browser Caching, which indicates wanting resources to expire 1 week or longer. One of the suggested JavaScript resources is Google's `analytics.js` which expires every 2 hours.

Would changing it's expiry somehow negatively affect my Google analytics data? If not, how would you go about changing an individual file name expiry manually (ie. *not* using a plugin). I always see expirys in the `.htaccess` file just grouped by entire file extensions (eg. `<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg)$">`) and never targeting a single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no control over the headers of the Google Analytics javascript file, as it is not served by your server. The .htaccess rules you mentioned can only apply to your own files.

You'll just have to ignore that particular error, and hope Google make the file a bit more cache friendly in future.